# How i can compare value in wordpress custom post type loop using taxonomy as key

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to search posts by comparing the value that i am getting from URL with taxonomy of the post. But i couldn't get it right. Here is my code.

```
$vendita = $_GET['vendita'];
$the_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
            'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name',
            // 'paged' => $paged,
            'meta_query' => array(
                'key' => 'taxonomy',
                'value' => $vendita,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are going to take parameters, you must always sanitize them, like with `$vendita = sanitize_text_field($_GET['vendita']);`.

This is not tested, but I think what you are looking for is this WP_Query

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
             'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'custom_taxonomy_slug',
                  'field'    => 'slug',
                  'terms'    => $vendita,
                   ),
               ),                
        )
    );
```

Note the 'field' can be the term_id or the name instead of the slug, I do not know what $vendita is exactly.

Note tax_query is a nested array, it must be that way.

Note: You can replace `array()` with the shorter `[]`.

Note: From docs: If you use the_post() with your query, you need to run wp_reset_postdata() afterwards to have template tags use the main query’s current post again.